# WIndows EC2 Instances with Failed Status Checks When Recover From AMI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, instance

We have Windows 2016 EC2 instances running without any issues. 
After stopped target instance, we took AMI and tried to create other instance from it as recovery drill, then always encountered the instance status check error 2/2 -- connectivity error. 
Rebooting and re-creation of other AMI and the new instance can't solve the issue. Also we couldn't take any valid system log, just black screen, for our trouble shooting.

For your information, the original instance is a member of Active Directory outside AWS, connected through VPN. And has fixed local IP address and looking DNS Server outside AWS. We also changed timezone from UTC to JST +9:00.

We'd like to know how to avoid this issue and recover the instance from AMI without any issue.

Any advice and your experience would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Just wondering if it would help to run `sysprep` before taking the image? This way, the new machine will be allocated a unique Windows ID rather than appearing as an exact clone.

Comment: *"And has fixed local IP address"*  That sounds like a misconfiguration.  EC2 instances should use DHCP.  The address offered to the instance by DHCP will not change, but you shouldn't have configured it statically, if that is what you are saying you did.

Comment: @John Rotenstein Many thanks again, John. We'll try EC2 Config sysprep :)

Comment: @Michael - sqlbot Thanks a lot, Michael. We tried both IP address automatically allocated by DHCP and fixed IP address in the range of attached VPC subnet. Unfortunately, both encountered the same error though.